# UINavigationController back button doesn't pop to previous VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I have a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540130/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-action-problem), but with a different cause it appears.

I have A nav controller with Views A>B>C>D>E.

In C I push to D, in which users "create a new session".  Sometimes users want to add detail to this new session, so they click add detail which pushes to E.

When they don't choose to add detail they press "done" on D, I call `[navControler popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` and they end up in C without the problem mentioned in the question above, meaning if on C they press back, it successfully goes to B.  However, when they do add detail, they go to E and when finished they press the nav ctrl's back button.  At that point I added this code to take them back to C:

```
    NSArray *allViewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
    for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) {
        if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[TSessionMgmtViewController class]]) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

They end up back at C, but when they hit the back button on C, it does the strange back animation but ends up on C again.  Then pressing back a second time takes them back to B.

I have already checked the following:
I am not calling extra `notifications` that cause an extra C to be pushed.
I am not pushing C in any other way
I checked the nav controller stack with     `NSLog(@"nav controller stack: %@",    [[self navigationController] viewControllers]);`  and it does not show an extra C on the stack.

So is this a problem with the back button itself on C?  Or is there some invisible C view controller that's there but does not show when printing the stack?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Where did you add the code you posted? You shouldn't change the behavior of the back button, if that's what you did -- it's meant to go back to the previous controller only, it shouldn't skip a controller. If you want to go directly from E to C, you should have a custom button to do that.

Comment: @rdelmar I added it in viewWillDisappear of E.

Comment: As I said in my comment, you shouldn't change the behavior of the back button -- users expect that will take them back one controller, not two. I would add a custom button (in E) to replace the back button, and add the code you posted to its action method, rather than putting it in viewDidDisappear. I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the nav controller for the list of vcs, but the first time you call pop, they change! You should just choose one to pop to. Or use a nav cont subclass and add logic to it so when you just pop the top controller, the one under it ( in its viewWillAppear) can query to see what it's suppose to do.